# Capacitor how to trigger forward button click?

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have `ionic 5` with `capacitor` in `angular` project to deploy app as cross-platform.In android devices I'd like to manipulate back and forward button/swipe clicks in case at least one modal is active.App should go back if there is no active modal otherwise modal should be closed only without navigating user.To do that I did implementation in `appComponent` as below which is working perfectly for back button.

```
import { App } from '@capacitor/app';

  App.addListener('backButton', () => {
        if (this.activeModalInstance) {
               this.activeModalInstance.close();
            }
             else {
               this._location.back();
             } 
      });
```

Unfortunately on forward button or swipe action this 'backButton' is working and navigating back since I have `location.back()` inside.I need to figure out how to determine either back or forward applied.How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated,** on `Ionic 6.x` and `Capacitor 4.6.3` a simple way to do that is calling `(keyup.enter)` in the html ion-input tag.

```
<ion-item button color="primary">
  <ion-input type="submit" placeholder="Login" (keyup.enter)="login(form)">
    Login
  </ion-input>
</ion-item>
```